# Pydoop Java home not set installation issue

Tags: java, python, hadoop

When I echo `$JAVA_HOME` I am getting the path of Java. Hadoop is also running, but pydoop installation fails due to this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 54, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("java home not found, try setting JAVA_HOME")
RuntimeError: java home not found, try setting JAVA_HOME
```

I run setup command with `sudo python setup.py install --skip-build`.
As a non root user getting this error
running install
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydoop
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydoop': Permission denied

Comment: How do you run setup? With sudo?

Comment: sudo python setup.py install --skip-build

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you run your setup with sudo, it is run under root account, where possibly no JAVA_HOME is defined.

You can opt to:

- export correct JAVA_HOME for root;
- or use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to install pydoop in an virtual environment under your current user without need to sudo;
- or use setup [options](http://docs.python.org/2/install/#alternate-installation) to specify build and install directory with no root privileges needed.

Comment: As a non root user on running install
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydoop
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydoop': Permission denied

Comment: @Aravinth did you read about custom folder specification, second and third links in my answer? Your error indicates that you don't have permissions in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/`, which is normal.

Comment: @Aravinth as you are stucked with this error, I conclude you're new to unix, so strongly suggest second option, virtual env usage.

Comment: changed the permissions now getting error: cannot copy tree 'build/scripts-2.7': not a directory

Comment: @Aravinth did you specify `--skip-build` on purpose? as it seems you didn't build. And `install` command simply copies built files to needed locations. And you seems to lack build.

Comment: If i specify python setup.py build my system get hanged so thats why mentioned it as --skip-build

Answer (score 2):

@alko is right. If you setting hadoop PATH or JAVA_HOME under your account, it's hard to directly solve it. Setting all envronment for root is complex and unnecessary.

But you can install pydoop under your account only. Install it to your ~/.local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packtes/pydoop-X.X.X/... path.

Use this command, if you download source tar file.

```
python setup.py install --user
```

or this

```
pip install pydoop --user
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when installing pydoop, though I set JAVA_HOME correctly by "export JAVA_HOME=myJavaHomePath", I still got the same error saying that "RuntimeError: java home not found, try setting JAVA_HOME".

In the end, I solved it by modifying the function "def get_java_home()" in file jvm.py, which is located in the path "/pydoop/pydoop/utils", as indicated in the error message.

I simply commented line return os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] and added line return "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64" in try clause, shown as below. /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 is the JAVA_HOME on my PC.

```
def get_java_home():
    try:
        #return os.environ["JAVA_HOME"]
        return "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"
    except KeyError:
        raise RuntimeError("java home not found, try setting JAVA_HOME")
```